# CSS not linking to HTML Page Template

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I tried in the `localhost wordpress` and it works fine there.

But when I try for my live website and try to link the CSS files to the HTML file I do not get the CSS effects.

I link the CSS to my HTML file using the following address location :

```
<link href="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ThemeName/file1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

How can I possibly link the CSS files to my HTML?

PS : I am linking my HTML file to my PHP file to create the Page Template as

```
require(TEMPLATEPATH.'/file1.html')
```

Also there is no folder named `wordpress` in the control panel directory.
The address location for my HTML and CSS file is `/home3/username/public_html/wp-content/themes/ThemeName/file1.html`

Comment: Incude the css in the html file?

Comment: @Epodax Yes I have linked the CSS to my HTML file.

Comment: Try to see the path from the page source

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I posted the path to my `HTML` and `CSS` files in the question. What path should I give in the `<link />`

Comment: If `template_url` didn't work for you, You can use a variable to give the css folder's path and use concat to link it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't write full path like that in your template. Wordpress provide functions for that, like `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` that returns the uri of your current theme folder. So to link your css you should do this:

```
<link href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/file1.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But you should consider linking your css from `functions.php` as it's a better practice:

```
function my_scripts()
{
  wp_enqueue_style( 'my_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/file1.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

That way Wordpress will add the `<link>` tag for your stylesheet in the head when `wp_head()` is called.

Comment: the `function.php` part am I supposed to write in the `PHP` file that I am using to create the page template ?

Comment: It's the `functions.php` file that is provided in your theme folder

Comment: So how am I supposed to use this `function.php` file to link my `CSS` ?

Comment: You just put inside it the code in my original post. It's a hook : you define a function that tell wordpress  to add your css to the WP stylesheet queue ; then you tell Wordpress to execute that function when he's supposed to enqueue the scripts / stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

css files can be included in the theme like this 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/file1.css"/>`
or you can use wp_enque_style() function

Comment: what will we write in the `template_url` ?

Comment: bloginfo('template_url'), it is a wordpress theme function. It returns your current theme url

Answer (score 0):

If you store css and html in same folder. I think It works:

```
  <link href="file1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Maybe something went wrong. I tried and it's always OK

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to specify the type:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ThemeName/file1.css">
```