# CSS not linked to HTML page

Tags: html, css

Good morning guys,

I am playing around building a small website. In the `html` I have my `link` to my `CSS` file but for some reason the `CSS` is not being shown on the page.

The link `tag` looks as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css" type="text/css">
```

The site does not contain any styles that I have built. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What is the folder structure? Which Web server are you using? File protocol?

Comment: Put it in the same folder as your html file, and then change it to href="style.css". Does it work? If so, move it into the styles folder and change it to href="styles/style.css". Still working? It either of them dont, its not a path issue, its something to do with your configuration.

Comment: First check your browser console for any linking error & then check the network panel. Please share your folder structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS not linking to HTML Page Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639644/css-not-linking-to-html-page-template)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Folder Structure 1**

- index.html
- styles (folder)

  - style.css

If this the folder structure then your link tag should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

**Folder Structure 2**

- index.html
- style.css

If your folder structure is like the above then the link tag should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
```

**Folder Structure 3**

- HTML (folder)

  - index.html
- styles (folder)

  - style.css

If your folder structure is like above then the link tag should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

This might help you. For any error check the browser console.

Comment: Thank you, i just needed to ommit the `./` from the path.

Comment: @OwenNel — Omitting `./` should make no difference. It just means "here".

Comment: @OwenNel ./ means the current directory / location

Answer (score -1):

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Try to include the code to head as I show above for mystyle.css rewrite your own css file make sure to have the same name as your css file is check if a letter is capital .
I saw  also you write text/css instead of test.css which is correct .